# Is it possible to delete a single file in a shelf?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Iv'e made changes to several files and shelved them (the original ones were restored). Since then, one of the files was deleted in the repository and when I synced, from my working copy too. When I unshelve, my edited copy of the file causes merge problems (rejects) because the shelf lists it as edited, while it does not exist anymore in the working copy.

I would like to delete it directly from the shelf, but I do not see an option for that. If it's not possible, what is the correct way to deal with this situation?

I'm using TortoiseHg, but answers don't need to be specifically for that.

Comment: If you are using THG then I think the answers do need to be specific to that tool. Although HG has its own shelf extension, that is not what THG uses (AFAIK). THG seems to have implemented its own shelving system and the two are not interoperable.

Comment: @DaveInCaz I was not aware of that. I thought that any hg command in the console of ToirtoiseHG would work (and that it's just a GUI for Mercurial). I added the tag.

Comment: I think THG's shelf is an exception, and you are correct in any other case I can think of. It might have been that THG added the feature before the hg shelve command (which is an extension) existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to update to a changeset which did contain the file that later got deleted, ideally the one upon which the shelved changes were based. Then you can unshelve the file into your working folder which removes it from the shelf, and subsequently revert that file assuming you don't need its modified contents.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar. When viewing a changeset it's possible to revert only selected files to a parent revision (`Ctrl+Shitf+R`). So I went to the revision where the files were deleted, reverted them into existence and then unshelved.

Answer (score 2):

In the thg Shelve tool you could right click on one of the shelved items and edit the patch.

[image]

This shows the entire patch for the Shelve. You have to be careful to only delete the patch for the file you want to exclude.

Alternatively:

When unshelving why not just unshelve each file individually, and ignore the missing file.

[image]